# Ways to see if a function $f(z)$ is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Despite I'm going to use an example to illustrate what I'm referring to, this pretends to be a general question about the procedure to find where a function is holomorphic.

Suppose we have

$$f(z)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/z^2} \quad z\neq 0\\ 0 \qquad\ \ \ \ z=0\end{cases}$$

We want to see if this function is holomorphic.

As far as I'm concerned, we have 2 ways to, in practise, see it:

- If this function has partial derivatives everywhere except on $0$, we can find if C-R equation holds for $f(z)$. Then, everywhere where $f(z)$ satisfies this equations, the function will be holomorphic.
- If it's hard (like on this example) to separate $f(z)$ in its real and imaginary part to verify that, we can verify if the function is $C^1(\Omega)$, and then we know that $\partial f/ \partial \bar{z}=0$ iff the function is holomorphic.

Am I correct? Did I leave any case? Is there another (easier) way to see that $f(z)$ is (isn't) holomorphic?

Comment: Are you familiar with the term "essential singularity"?

Comment: No, we haven't did this yet.

Comment: Well once you've covered it, you can come back to this question and show $f$ has an essential singularity at 0. We can prove it's not holomorphic at 0 though, in fact it's not continuous there. It's holomorphic as a function in $\mathbb{R}$ since if $x \to 0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $-\frac{1}{x^2}$ will go to $- \infty$ so $f(x) \to 0$. Why does this fail in the complex plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to note $e^z$ is holomorphic everywhere, and $-1/z^2$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}.$ Therefore the composition, $e^{-1/z^2},$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}.$ What happens at $0?$ There $f$ is not differentiable, or even continuous. To see this, consider $f(z)$ as $z\to 0$ along the imaginary axis.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is not even continuous at the origin, so of course it can't be holomorphic. A way to show this: try to take $z \to 0$ on the real axis, and then on the imaginary axis. You will get different limits, so the function is not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is whether your function is continuous or not. And it isn't: $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x+xi)\neq0$.

Besides, you should be aware of the fact that a point of the domain of $f$ may well be a solution of the Cauchy-Riemann equations and, even so, $f$ may not be differentiable there.

Comment: So $f(z)$ is holomorphic everywhere except an open interval around $0$ right?
And if I check that the partial derivatives are continuous everywhere and that CR eq. holds for $f(z)$, isn't my function holomorphic?

Comment: First question: no. The function $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Second question: yes.