# Is $f(z)$ entire?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, entire-functions

> I am trying to determine if the the following is entire $$f(z)= \begin{cases}  
>       e^{-z^{-4}} & z\neq0 \\
>       0 & z=0\\
>    \end{cases}
> $$

My attempt:

Consider $z\ne 0$. $f(z)=e^{-z^{-4}}$ is the composition of two differentiable functions, hence $f$ is differentiable when $z\neq 0$.

Next I considered $z=0$. The Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied at $z=0$, as $u_x=u_y=v_x=v_y=0$. But this is not sufficient condition for complex differentiability. I wish to show $f$ is continuous/discontinuous at $z=0$.

I tried defining the limit $$f(z)=\lim_{z\to 0} e^{-z^{-4}}=e^{-\infty}=0$$

This would imply $f$ is continuous at $z=0$, but the answer I have disagrees.

**edit**

If I let $z=re^{i\theta}$, then 
\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to 0} e^{-z^{-4}}&=\lim_{r\to 0} e^{-\frac{1}{r^4}e^{-4i\theta}} \\
&=\lim_{r\to 0} e^{\frac{1}{r^4}}\rightarrow \infty \ \ \ \ \text{letting} \left(\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \\
\end{align}
Hence, $f$ is not continuous at $z=0\implies f$ is not differentible at $z=0$.

So $f$ is not entire.

Comment: Try calculating the Taylor series expansion at $z=0$, you'll be surprised...

Comment: Almost duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2717209/ways-to-see-if-a-function-fz-is-holomorphic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ways to see if a function $f(z)$ is holomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2717209/ways-to-see-if-a-function-fz-is-holomorphic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: consider $z=x+xi$ for real $x\to0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having trouble computing this limit. I understand that we're trying to find a limit that doesn't approach 0, but I'm having trouble with the calculations. Does the limit exist?

Comment: @Bell If $z = x + ix$ (or maybe it's easier to use $\frac1{\sqrt2}(x+ix)$ since that has absolute value 1, you decide), what is $z^4$, in terms of $x$? What is $z^{-4}$? What is $-z^{-4}$? What happens to this expression when $x\to 0$? What happens to the exponential?

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. I also tried another way (in my edit above), by considering a ray inclined by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ from the positive real axis. Does this also work?

Comment: @Bell It's exactly the same approach, only geometrically rather than algebraically ($x+xi$ 
for real $x$ is that line, and if you also say $x>0$ you get the ray). So yes, that ought to give the same result.

Answer (score 3):

For each positive interger $n$ lat $c_n$ be a fourth root of $ {2ni\pi} $ and $z_n = \frac 1 {c_n}$Then $|e^{-z_n^{-4}} |=1$ for all $n$ and $z_n \to 0$.